# Textures and RingGeometry / CylinderGeometry

Tags: three.js, textures

UPDATE:
I made jsfiddle example - [jsfiddle.net/NEXny/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/NEXny/1/)

```
[ignore this - just including a code block so stackoverflow will
```

let me post the above JSFiddle link.  Yeah, seriously.]

I'm having trouble with applying texture to RingGeometry and CylinderGeometry, hope this image will explain my issue.

[image: texture]

It is possible to apply texture by one of this ways ?
Currently i'm getting very unexpected results...

Comment: You have to modify the geometry vertex UVs to your liking. Instead, why not just use a `CircleGeometry` for your cylinder end-caps. http://jsfiddle.net/NEXny/2/

Comment: Look like CircleGeometry it the best chose, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to modify the geometry vertex UVs to your liking.

Instead, why not just use `CircleGeometry` for your cylinder end-caps. That is, construct the end-caps yourself?

```
// cylinder
geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 192, 192, 40, 64, 1, true ); // open-ended
geometry1 = new THREE.CircleGeometry(192, 64);

// end-cap material
material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
    map: textures.circle,
    overdraw: 0.5 // for canvas renderer only
});

// cylinder material
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
    map: textures.line,
    overdraw: 0.5 // for canvas renderer only
});

object = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(object);

// end-caps
var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1);
mesh1.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
mesh1.position.y = 20
object.add(mesh1);

var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1);
mesh2.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
mesh2.position.y = -20
object.add(mesh2);

// cylinder
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
object.add(mesh);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NEXny/2/

three.js r.61